# How to collect values from a specific cell in data grid control into a variable in VB 6.0?

Tags: datagrid, vb6

I have tried this code:

```
Form2.DataGrid1.Columns(2).value
```

But the problem is it generates values of 1st row. how to find the values of suppose (rows=2,column=3)
Any Help Please!

Answer (score 0):

Yup, succeeded! Here is the code:

```
 Dim x as String   
 x = DataGrid1.RowBookmark(row)
 Msgbox DataGrid1.Columns(cols).CellValue(x)
```